# Get a list of all non nil properties of an object

Tags: ios, objective-c

Consider an object of TypeA below:

```
@interface TypeA : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * alpha
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * beta;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * gamma;

@end
```

Consider an instance below:

```
TypeA *someType = [[TypeA alloc] init];
someType.alpha = @"alpha";
someType.gamma = @"gamma";
```

At this point, I have an API call:

```
- (void)updateTypeWithTypeInfo:(TypeA *info)
{
   // info.gamma = nil
   // so I don't want gamma to be overwritten
}
```

Above is a simple use case; a bit verbose but I wanted to get the point across.

**Q1.** Is there a way to get a list of non NULL properties from type `TypeA`

**Q2.** Is there a fast way to overwrite values in an update for only values that exist? So even if I know the answer to Q1, it doesn't help a great deal. I still have to write a small for loop and set the value of the properties myself. Is there an easier/simple/short way of doing the above?

Comment: I don't think there is a shortcut approach. You have to compare the properties one by one  and update the value of a property if it is not nil.

Comment: Sooner or later you have to actually write code.

Comment: If you don't want `nil` values, use `init` to set them to something else.

Comment: (Of course, most sensible programmers would just use an NS(Mutable)Dictionary, if all you're doing is passing an arbitrary list of parameters.)

Comment: You could do this by using `class_copyPropertyList` and looping through all the properties to find the non-nil ones, but I would advise against it.